# What are conditions to make f(x) defined by f(x)=f(x-1)*x + 1/e unique(for instance convex)?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, gamma-function, functional-equations

[Background:]
Looking at the powerseries for the gamma-function

$  \Gamma(1+x) = 1 + a_1 x + a_2 x^2 - a_3 * x^3 + ... $

then we can arrive at a decomposition

$  \Gamma(1+x) =  r(x) + g(x)  $

where g(x) is constructed by the sum of the (taylor-expansions of) geometric series

```
          1      1      1   1     1   1    
  g(x) = ---  - --- +  ---*--- - ---*--- + ...   
         1+x    2+x    3+x  2!   4+x  3!

                                               [edit:corrected a sign-error]
```

and from this the powerseries for r(x)

$ r(x) = \Gamma(1+x) - g(x) $

[end background]

That function r(x) begins with

$ r(x) = 1/e + 0.21938 * x + 0.09784 *x^2 + \ldots $

The function has then some nice properties. By heuristics and inspection of its powerseries
it seems for instance, that

- apparently it is entire, has no zero except that  $ lim_{x-> \infty} r(-x) = 0 $
- $ r(0) = 1/e  $ where $ e = \exp(1) $
- $ r(k) = r(k-1)*k + 1/e $

Just today I found, that in fact this is the incomplete gamma-
function as defined/implemented in mathematica as "gamma(1+x,1)".
But this may not be of concern here, because I want to understand how to think the other way round:

- Question 1:

  Assume we had only the functional relation and the initial value

  $  r(x) = r(x-1)*x +1/e $  
  $  r(0) = 1/e $

  what else would we need to make r(x) unique and arrive at the solution

  $ r(x) = \Gamma(1+x)-g(x) $

  ?
- Question 2:

  Is there any way to generalize that construction scheme to
  get some function f(x) where the functional equation depends
  on a constant parameter c =/= 0

  $ f(x) = f(x-1)*x + c $

  For instance let $ c=1/2 $ . What would a -for instance convex - function $ f(x)$ look like?

  [update]: Question 2 seems to be easy - at the integer x f(x) is simply a scaling of r(x) by c and e:  $ f(x)= r(x)*c*e $
  so I'd assume the same can be assumed for fractional x.

Comment: $g(x)$ doesn't look like a geometric series, and it doesn't look like a Taylor expansion, so I'm stuck at the beginning. 

Comment: Well, it is meant that we take each term of g(x) as formal powerseries and construct the formal powerseries g(x) as alternating sums over the coefficients at equal powers of x .
   g(x) =   (1 - x + x^2 - x^3 + ...     )
        -1/2(1 -1/2 x + 1/4 x^2 - 1/8 x^3 + ...)   
        +1/6(1 -1/3 x + 1/9 x^2 - 1/27 x^3 + ...)     
        -1/24 ( ...)     
        + (...)


Comment: I've put my notes together in
 http://go.helms-net.de/math/musings/ReducingGamma%28draft%29.pdf
It is still a draft but meant to illustrate the exploration which led me to my question. Also while I'm working this out I'm getting the  impression that this all might be a bit trivial for MO and better be stacked elsewhere. Sorry, if that is the case (it was my first question here)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm answering my own question... :-)

I found that book of Emile Artin on the "Theory of the Gamma-function" and a very nice text of Philip Davis(1959) on "Leonard Euler's Integral" which both dealt very explanative with the uniqueness-problem and the specific topic of convexity.

That answers my question 1) - I'll just have to get some more practice with this.